# How can i "look at data" in my Grails h2 data source in a Linux/Grails/Groovy environment?

Tags: sql, database, grails, groovy, h2

I know if i have an SQLite database I can use DBrowser for SQLite, but I am working on a Grails project now and was wondering what the best tool for looking at the entries in tables in my DB?

Here is what I'm using for a DB and my DataSource.groovy config file (well, part of it...):

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
                // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just navigate to your app, and add `dbconsole` on the end of that URL. 
So, if your app is called AWESOMEAPP, you just navigate to:

```
localhost:8080/AWESOMEAPP/dbconsole
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.1/guide/conf.html#databaseConsole